# How to wrap text for mysql database results in PhpStorm

Tags: configuration, phpstorm, preferences

I'm wondering if there is a way to wrap text in the database tab in PhpStorm.
There are some very long results that goes further than I'm able to see.

Here is how that looks like:

[image]

Are there any kind of settings or preferences that can wrap text for mysql results in PhpStorm?

I'm using PhpStorm version 2019.1.1

**EDIT**

I found something that *might* solve this issue: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/database-tool-window.html (CTRL + F wrap), but I simply cannot find the icon for "Foreign Data Wrapper"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign data wrappers are a concept in Postgres for remote object access. You're looking at the wrong docs, the **database tool window** is the one where you can create/configure datasources, the window that shows the data is the **database console's result pane**.

Anyways, AFAICT there is no way (yet) to show the columns wrapped by default. Only when for the edit mode you can activate soft wrapping. Double click on the column or hit F2, then use **View > Active Editor > Soft Wrap**.

[image: PhpStorm View Menu]

In **File > Settings > Keymap** you can put that on a shortcut for easier access.

[image: PhpStorm Keymap Settings]

If you enable soft-wrapping for all "files" by specifying `*` in **File > Settings > Editor > General > Soft-wrap files**, then the table editor's edit mode is affected by it too and will wrap in edit mode by default.

[image: PhpStorm Editor Settings]

See also

- **https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5534**
- **https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1951**
- **https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.1/settings-keymap.html**
- **https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.1/database-console.html#f90b0d14**
- **https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.1/table-editor.html**
- **https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.1/settings-editor-general.html**

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, I've added that one to the answer.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: if you have soft-wraps enabled by default (for all files -- `*`) then `Edit` and `Edit Maximized` will use soft-wraps with no additional moves required.

Comment: The Jetbrains folks are really good at hiding behavior like that :) Added that to the answer too, thanks again @LazyOne.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So for now, it only seems like wrapping is possible if I double-click the column

Comment: I cant believe there is no way to show the columns wrapped by default. It is frustrating.